# How get name of table in result array in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I use some indexes in one file `sphinx.conf`. When I give result array from these indexes(different tables Mysql) I don't get names of tables. How I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify sql_query attribute of your indexes in sphinx.conf so they will return one fake attribute - index name.

For example:

```
first_idx:
...
sql_query = SELECT <...>, 'first_idx' as index_name FROM fisrt_table;


second_idx:
...
sql_query = SELECT <...>, 'second_idx' as index_name FROM second_table;
```

Comment: The best way to do it use: `$s->setSelect('type');` Where `$s` is object `$s = new SphinxClient;`